# IPython will not start in Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, ipython, tornado, anaconda

I am using an Anaconda 32-bit intallation of python 2.7.5.

When I try ipython notebook at prompt or via Anaconda launcher the Chrome tab opens at 127.0.0.1:8888 and all I get is a blank, white browser screen.

C&P of 127.0.0.1:8888 into IE10 correctly opens with no problem.

The command prompt for `ipython notebook -debug` shows:

```
[tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET api/sessions?_=1385980866174 (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
```

I am not connected through any proxies.

**UPDATE**

I realize now that localhost:8888 works on Chrome.
IS there some setting I can change so that when it defaults to 127.0.0.1:8888 IPython runs, rather than change to localhost every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned IE10, I am assuming you are on Windows.

You problem is very strange. 127.0.0.1 **should** be equivalent to `localhost` regardless of your browser. If it works in IE10, then it indicates that it is a problem with Chrome and not your OS. You should check your HOSTS file nonetheless.

Try clearing Chrome's browser cache, user profiles etc. Even going so far as re-installing Chrome might get things to work.

Comment: clearing browser cache worked. Still no idea why this happened.